# Sequelize and Graphql reverse lookup

Tags: express, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have two Models:

```
River.associate = models => {
  River.hasMany(models.Fish, { as: 'Fishes' });
};

Fish.associate = models => {
  Fish.belongsTo(models.River);
};

type River {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    alternative: String!
    geojson: JSON
    fishes: [Fish]
}

type Fish {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

**How would I findAll Rivers given a list of Fish ID's?** Im not sure how the query must look for this for graphql and sequelize?

```
type Query {
  river(id: ID!): River
  **rivers(fishIds: ARRAY): River ??????**
  fishes: [Fish]
}

Query: {
rivers: (_, { fishIds }) => {
      return River.findAll({
        where: {
          fishes: fishIds
        }
      });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `WHERE` clauses for each of the models you include. Moreover, doing so will convert the eager load to an inner join (which is what you want), unless you explicitly set the `required` param to `false`.

That means you should be able to do something like:

```
River.findAll({ include:
  [
    {
      model: Fish,
      where: { id: fishIds }
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: This seems to be working, although my associations are not working and now nothing is returned. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935562/associations-not-working-for-sequelize